# Cant add or update a child row because of constraint fail. Parent row has data

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

Trying to insert data via PutDatabaseRecord in NiFi. I Inferred the schema via InferAvroSchema. 8 out of 16 tables inserted the data inside the tables, all the other have the error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" The parent table has data inside.

With NiFi it fails ( "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ") but when I do it via SQL "Insert data into ..." It works.

Parent table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE soccer_city
(
    city_id int(11),
    city varchar(255),
    country_id int(11),
    CONSTRAINT id2
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES soccer_country (country_id)
);
```

The failed table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE soccer_venue
(
    venue_id int(11),
    venue_name varchar(255),
    city_id int(11),
    aud_capacity int(11),
    CONSTRAINT id3
    PRIMARY KEY (venue_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES soccer_city (city_id)
);
```

The table schema :

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "soccer_venue_schema",
    "fields": 
  [
      {"name": "venue_id", "type": ["null","string"]},
      {"name": "venue_name", "type": ["null","string"]},
      {"name": "city_id", "type": ["null","string"]},
      {"name": "aud_capacity", "type": ["null","string"]}
  ]
}
```

Comment: If there is a constraint violation then it means the row being inserted into soccer_venue references a city_id that is not in the soccer_city table, or the venue_id already exists. You need to look at the data for the records that are failing, not the schema.

Comment: soccer_venue.csv

venue_id,venue_name,city_id,aud_capacity
20001,Stade de Bordeaux,10003,42115
20002,Stade Bollaert-Delelis,10004,38223
20003,Stade Pierre Mauroy,10005,49822


soccer_city.csv

city_id,city,country_id
10003,Bordeaux,1207
10004,Lens,1207
10005,Lille,1207

This are the data samples, soccer_venue has no data in the database, and 'city_id' in 'soccer_city' correspond to 'soccer_venue'.